# Mutilevel dropdown with scrollbar issue

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

As I have a very long menu list, I want to limit them with **scroll**.

In this [codepen demo](https://codepen.io/ronaldaug/pen/KKPbwyw) , It is working fine without scroll.

But if I added `overflow-y:scroll; height:200px;`, it causes **overflow-x** and hide all dropdowns as below screenshot.

[image: with scroll]

I found this [smart menu](https://www.smartmenus.org/about/themes/#demos-gallery) library that does the job.

But my question is - how can I achieve this without a library?

Answer (score 0):

It might not be possible with just CSS.

What you really need is JavaScript. Because without it you are just setting the visibility of the inner lists to `visibility: hidden` and items with visibility set to hidden are taken in consideration when generating the layout of a `div` or a page. This is the reason there is overflow in the x direction.

With just CSS you will have to set a constant width of the main list that can accommodate the inner lists.

Below is the CSS that I tried and works with fixed width. Put it in place of the CSS that you are adding. So instead of this:

```
li.dropdown ul {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 300px;
}
```

Add this:

```
li.dropdown ul {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  height: 300px;
  width: 450px;
}

li {
   width: 100px;
}
```

Comment: I tried your codes but the width `450px` is static and dropdown's left position moved. It's not what I want to achieve. Anyway, thanks. I'll probably have to implement with JS. Any idea for JS?

Comment: I think it would involve setting the display of the inner lists to `display: none`.
I could have told you in much more detail if you had not been using `display: flex`. I just don't have much experience with it